# Barra de progreso css

Tags: css

Estoy haciendo una barra de progreso simple usando `<progress>`, pero tengo un error cuando le agrego animación, sigue de largo y no me respeta el `width: 100px;`

```css
progress {
border: none;
border-radius: 2rem;
width: 100%;
height: 9px;
animation: prog 2s linear;
}

::-webkit-progress-bar-value {background-color: #1DA1F2; border-radius: 2rem;}
::-webkit-progress-value {background-color: #1DA1F2; border-radius: 2rem;}
::-moz-progress-bar {background-color: #1DA1F2; border-radius: 2rem;}

@keyframes prog {
0% {width: 0%; background-color: #f1f1f1;}
100% {width: 100% color: #000;}
}
```

```html
<progress max="100" value="76"></progress>
```

Modifiqué el código tratando de que funcione y bueno, por ahora funciona... pero el ejemplo de abajo esta mejor...

Comment: Con CSS solo podrias hacerlo para Chrome que tiene el pseudo-elemento  `::-webkit-progress-value ` pero no funcionará en otros navegadores. Puedes simular la barra como dice @Csharls en su respuesta o acceder al `value` de `progress` con javascript y modificarlo

Comment: Tal como dice @blonfu, ese ejemplo no dibuja nada en Firefox. Es un simple div sin relleno. Probablemente ahora que todo se hace usando web components ya se hará cada vez más infrecuente ver nuevos tags nativos siendo implementados

Comment: @amenadiel yo no he dicho eso, el elemento `progress` se ve prefectamente en Firefox y el resto de navegadores pero no podrá animarlo con CSS en navegadores que no usen `webkit`

Comment: @blonfu oye... tienes razón, una vez intenté algo parecido y no funcionó, pero supongo que el problema fue otro. Disculpen la ignorancia :(

Comment: Gracias a todos, la verdad trate de hacerlo solo con progress, pero vi que para explorador tiene un formato distinto hasta para colocar un color de fondo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hola el problema es que estas cambiando el Ancho (Width) de la etiqueta `progress`, lo que tienes que hacer es aumentar el valor del atributo `value`.

Tu lo que quieres es lograr un efecto como este usando solo CSS

```css
.barra { 
    height: 20px;
 position: relative;
 background: #555;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding: 10px;
}
.barra > span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #22AA11;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: prog 2s linear;
}
@keyframes prog {
  0% {width: 0%}
  100% {width: 100%}
}
```

```html
<div class="barra">
  <span style="width: 25%"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a publicar lo que hice, pero voy a tomar el tuyo... je....

Answer (score 4):

Sólo con fines académicos, y aunque sé que no es la respuesta que necesitas, noté que  **dado un elemento progress que sea indeterminado (sin value)** se puede animar el ancho del seudoelemento `::-moz-progress-bar`, pero los seudoelementos de webkit conservan su estilo inicial y no hacen caso a las animaciones. Ni el progress bar ni el progress value.

Sin embargo, dicho lo anterior, estos seudoelementos sí soportan transiciones. Pero como han de saber, una transición ocurre cuando un elemento sufre un cambio de estado como la adición de una clase. (o una seudoclase como :hover).

Lo siguiente funciona tanto en Chrome como en Firefox:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('#progreso').className = 'llenandose';
};
```

```css
progress {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background:none;
}


progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background:#36c;
  width:0;
  transition: width 2s linear; 
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background:#36c;
  width:0;
  transition: width 2s linear; 
}

.llenandose::-webkit-progress-bar {
  width:100%;
}
.llenandose::-moz-progress-bar {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<progress id="progreso">Progreso</progress>
```

Pero volvemos a los dos problemas iniciales:

- Esto no funciona en todos los browsers
- No estás manipulando el indicador de progreso según el valor del elemento sino con una animación arbitraria.

En realidad no creo que haya una manera de hacerlo con puro CSS. La alternativa sería combinar lo que te dice [Csharls](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16893/csharls) con un poco de javascript para ir actualizando el "seudoprogreso" acorde a la variación del valor real de la barra, que estaría oculta.

## Edit

Perdonen lo bruto... edité el fragmento de código para hacer un experimento y pisé lo que había hecho antes. Ahora lo restablecí.

Comment: Bueno, respecto al punto que nombras: "Esto no funciona en todos los browsers", lo que publicaste no funciona en mio y uso Firefox. Sin envargo los que hice funciona perfectamente solo con css. No pongo en duda tu conocimiento y agradezco tu tiempo, pero de manera en que lo uso, funciona perfectamente y desde mi punto de vista, veo que funciona bien sin javascript

Comment: En realidad rompí el código que había dejado por estar haciendo experimentos con ::before y ::after. Ahora lo restablecí. En todo caso, si tomaste el código de @csharls claro que funciona, pero sigue sin cumplir el tema de fondo que es vincular la animación con el valor del progreso real. No sé si esto sea realmente relevante, es una suposición.

Comment: Entiendo, pero tuve que tomas el mio, para poder agregarle php. Pero ahora te entendi y gracias